# Looking for Nanjing Mandarin Colloquial version (南京官话译本) of the New Testament

Tags: translation, resource-request

The Nanking Mandarin Colloquial Version (南京官话译本) of the entire New Testament (新约全书) was, supposedly, released in 1860~1861.

It was translated by Walter Henry Medhurst (麦都思) and Wang Tao (王韬) and published by The London Missionary Society Press (墨海书馆).

It seems to be the only "Southern Mandarin" translation that exists, which is referred to on Wikipedia's [List of Chinese Bible translations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_Bible_translations) page:

> **Mandarin Chinese**
>
> **Southern Mandarin**
>
> New Testament, 1856

I think Matthew was released in earlier, hence the disparity in dates.

Comment: There's a Chinese stack exchange too. Not that they're better equipped to find it, but I'm sure more of them speak Chinese.

Comment: Welcome! Is there a particular format you are looking for?  (hard copy book to purchase, PDF, other?)  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Comment: Hoping for a digital copy! Curious to see how it was translated. Although I've seen comments alluding that it was a poor translation.

Comment: Is the ["Delegates Version"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations_into_Chinese#Delegates_Version) not the same thing?

Comment: I believe it's translated from the Delegates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked Chinese websites for you and was able to find the following page where you can type in the chapter numbers and read the image of the copy of the book (in Chinese). 
http://hb.fhl.net/gbdoc/ob/ro.php?book=90&procb=1
Which it helps!

Comment: This was the first edition of the book 圣经珍藏:新约全书(南京官话译本初版)

Comment: I have actually answered this question - but it was deleted - I've voted to undelete my post but it's still sitting waiting.

Comment: No worries, my friend. May G-d be in everything you do through Christ, Amen :)

Comment: You can also add: http://bible.fhl.net/ob/ro.php?book=114&procb=1 this is an earlier version: (1856 Four Gospels & Acts Nanjing Translation)

Answer (score 1):

There's two versions below:

The later version is from 1857 and it is the complete New Testament:

- [1857 新約全書 (南京官話譯本初版)](http://bible.fhl.net/ob/ro.php?book=90&procb=1) (1857 New Testament Nanjing Translation)

> [image]
>
> 簡介：1854年，麥都思、施敦力以南京官話(白話文)改寫文言「委辦譯本」的新約全書，是中國第一本白話文譯本，史稱「麥都思、施敦力譯本」或「南京官話譯本」，於1857年出版。 http://bibletranslation-hk.blogspot.tw/2011/10/blog-post_1643.html
>
> 著作權資訊：影像著作權為澳洲雪梨 Dr. Kenny Wang 所有
>
> 提供者：Dr. Kenny Wang

The second, earlier, version  only contains the Gospels & Acts:

- [1856 新約四福音使徒行傳（南京官話譯本）](http://bible.fhl.net/ob/ro.php?book=114&procb=1) (1856 Four Gospels & Acts Nanjing Translation)

> [image]
>
> 簡介：1854年，麥都思、施敦力以南京官話(白話文)改寫文言「委辦譯本」的新約全書，是中國第一本白話文譯本，史稱「麥都思、施敦力譯本」或「南京官話譯本」，於1857年出版。 http://bibletranslation-hk.blogspot.tw/2011/10/blog-post_1643.html
>
> 著作權資訊：翻拍影像著作權是澳洲國立圖書館所有，註明出處為NLA後可以自由刊載
>
> 提供者：Dr. Kenny Wang